# Unsigned integer TIFF containing negative NoData value?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, bit-depth

**Background:**

At 10.8.1, I have an 32-bit, unsigned, integer TIFF raster. The NoData value is, as expected, 4,294,967,295 (2^32-1).

The values in this raster range from only 0-7, which makes a 32-bit depth overkill.  I thus decided to use the *Copy Raster* tool to reduce the bit depth, using Pixel Type = 4-bit.  The tool help states that the output will be an "...unsigned integer. The values supported can be from 0 to 15."

However, the tool's default output NoData Value is -1.  Sure enough, when using this default setting, the output is an unsigned 4-bit TIFF, where the NoData value = -1.

As far as I know, unsigned rasters can only contain positive values.  Since my output TIFF is unsigned, I would thus expect its NoData value to also be a positive integer, just as in the source 32-bit unsigned integer TIFF.

How can an unsigned integer TIFF contain a negative NoData value?

I'm asking this question in order to better understand raster technology in general.  I'm not asking how to "force" a postive NoData output value, which could be done by selecting a positive value in the *Copy Raster* tool, or by using the *Raster Calculator*, as commented by MoreMeowBell.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the issue? If so Raster Calculator is a great way to go about it.

Comment: 4-bit TIFF is rather uncommon. I have a feeling that it is physically stored as 8-bit. But if it is logically limited to 0-16 range then -1 values do feel wrong.

Comment: @user30184 raster is output as a Byte dataset, but actual data is definitely stored as 4bit, can check by looking at file sizes of uncompressed rasters  e.g using rasterio to write a 1-bit dataset https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/338424/2856 (note ArcGIS uses GDAL to write GeoTIFFs and uses the NBITS=N creation option)

Comment: The kind responses so far got me to wondering what QGIS would report about this 4-bit tif in Layer Properties. The result: Data Type is "Byte - Eight bit unsigned integer" and No-Data is "n/a".

Comment: @user2856 mea culpa regarding your confusion.  I rewrote my QGIS comment.

Comment: QGIS just ignores the NoData value as it's outside the valid range of the datatype

Comment: If your data range is 0-7 why not set no data to be 15 if you are to store it as a 4bit raster?

Comment: @Hornbydd You are correct, I *could* set NoData to 15.  But my question is asking "how is it possible for an **unsigned** raster to store a **negative** value in those cells designated NoData?  It has always been my assumption (possibly incorrect) that unsigned rasters could only store **positive** values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 4bit TIFF can't store values outside the range 0-15.  Just like an 8bit unsigned (Byte) raster can not store values outside of 0-255.

The NoData value is only metadata, it's just for telling ArcGIS or other software to ignore a specific value.  You can specify a NoData value that is outside the valid range of the datatype e.g. -1 in this case or -9999 if you like, but ArcGIS won't actually write -1 values to the output raster.  Where there is NoData in the input raster, they will be output as 0.

I suggest it's a bug that ArcGIS allows specifying a NoData value outside the range of the output datatype and then silently writing a different value to the output raster (the minimum value of the output datatype range).  The GDAL library that ArcGIS uses to write many raster formats also does this.

### Input (NoData shown in black)

[image: input]

### Output of Copy Raster 4bit with NoData = -1

[image: output]

```
gdalinfo test_4bit.tif
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
<snip...>
Band 1 ... Type=Byte, ...
  NoData Value=-1
  Image Structure Metadata:
    NBITS=4
```

As you have noticed, QGIS ignores the NoData value as it's outside the valid range of the datatype:

[image]

Comment: Your screenshots are interesting, and I want to make sure that I understand what they mean.  Specifically, the black (NoData) input cells are displayed as pink in the 4-bit output.  What happened to those NoData cells? Are they still NoData, or converted to some other value, or...?

Comment: "Where there is NoData in the input raster, they will be output as 0." means any NoData values will be converted to 0.